# Number field type for specific format

Tags: 8, entities

I have to store number data into database in format xx-xxxxxx-xx for example I have xml data in format:
ISBN="10-000000-701"
ISBN="11-000000-002"
ISBN="11-000000-004"

and I need to store that number in db field but I don't know what field type to use. Any help?

Comment: There is an ISBN field module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a 'simple text' field. Then you can [add a constraint](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint) to that field to ensure that it is in the correct format.

Comment: Sure. But in this specific case of OP: https://www.drupal.org/project/isbn